# Request Response transformation using freemarker in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, freemarker, json-schema-validator, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway Hoxton.M1 release to implement an API gateway. I have the following two spring boot apps -

Client <-> Router App <-> Wrapper App <-> Downstream application

Router App - This application has spring cloud gateway. All routes in application.yml point to a common REST controller end point in Wrapper application by passing a request header attribute "apiendpointid" to diff b/w diff api calls. Below is a sample route entry

```
  - id: milestone
    uri: http://localhost:5001
    predicates:
    - Path=/track/milestone
    - Method=POST
    filters:
    - RewritePath=/track/milestone,/gateway/api/internal/process
    - AddRequestHeader=apiendpointid,retailmilestone
    - AddRequestHeader=appid,retail
    - SecureHeaders
```

Wrapper App - This is a spring boot application which has Rest controller. Controller method does the following -

1. Identify JSON schema file basis the "apiendpointid" request
   header attribute and apply JSON schema validation. Reject request in
   case of schema validation failures by return 400 response to router
   app.
2. Identity the freemarker request transformation file basis the "apiendpointid" request header attribute and transform incoming request to downstream expected format.
3. Send request to downstream.
4. Transform response from downstream to expected format again using freemarker response template.
5. Send response back to router app.

This works fine but there is an extra http "hop" from router to wrapper. We have not yet gone live; so not very sure if it will be a performance concern.

Currently wrapper is not built in a reactive way. Also team does not have much expertise in reactive programming. Are there any production implementations built this way (i.e. having this extra wrapper layer/app in the middle) or is it better to integrate all wrapper functionalities into router app itself? If yes, could you please direct me to some examples where request/response transformations/schema validations are being done in spring cloud gateway itself?

Comment: Adding @spencergibb

Comment: Could anyone please direct me to a working example where request/response json transformations using freemarker or any other approach have been done previously using spring cloud gateway?

Comment: did you find any workaround for this?

Comment: @SJ.Jafari I did not find any solutions for this; so have gone ahead with above design. We have "modfiyRequestBody/modfiyResponseBody" filters in SCG but was not very sure how to incorporate all the wrapper logic into this in a reactive manner.